# Css only text link change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a simple bootstrap div with the text in the center.

**My question is :** is there anyway to change the class(already created in html or create in css?) of the div only using css and also change the text,link inside and then apply style to the text referring to the new class. This must be done using only css. Html must not be touched. Is this possible? Answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center;border:1px solid red">
<li><a href="#">CODING</a></li>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    background-color:#ffc425;

}
```

Comment: do you want mouse over effect or other effects to change the text

Comment: I wanted the basic text to only change using css. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: **No**.. CSS can't change classes, `#href` s or text. Your HTML is invalid by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above was just an example put together in codeply. :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS is a language that describes a style for html. You can't do any sort of scripting with it.
You can do it with `javascript` using

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container").className = "newClass";
```

or

```
document.getElementById(<id>).className = "newClass";
```

For changing text, same thing as above but `.innerHTML` instead of `.className`

Comment: Actually, I wanted to use change the "storefront designed by woothemes" in my website by using css. What I did was   .site-info a{
 visibility: hidden;
 word-spacing:-9999px;
 letter-spacing: -9999px;
}

.site-info:after{
 content: "threadsack team";
 text-transform: uppercase;
 visibility: visible;
 word-spacing: normal;
 letter-spacing: normal;
} but i still see . before the word and t's not a link anymore.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Before which word do you see a `.`?

Comment: It's --- Storefront designed by WooThemes before.....Now -- Storefront designed by . My Name